# System CPU Usage by User-Python

Tags: python, windows

Is there anyway that I can cross link all incoming users (netstat -a in CMD) to create a montior system to track the percentage of CPU used by each of the users in python. Does the Windows system write any log files on that? I have the CPU usage per process using psutil but i just cant figure out a way to display CPU usageby user. Please I need help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to figure out CPU usage per-user per-se.
What you might do is figure out the CPU usages of processes owned by a certain user as in:

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.username == 'someusername':
        print p.get_cpu_percent(interval=1)
```

Summing all of them in order to obtain a total is unlikely to produce a meaningful value though.

Comment: It gives me an error saying I do not have permission. Does psutil have any disk queue length measurement?

Comment: Starting from next version most of permissions-related exceptions will be solved. In the meantime you can just trap the exception and skip to the next process. And no, no disk queue length stats of any kind.