# How to get a users processing percent in windows

Tags: python

What i want  to extract is the CPU column of the below screenshot of the Task Manager using python.

[image]

I know that `psutil.cpu_percent()` will return the overall CPU usage but i want to know it based on the users loged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `psutil` package it seems like you can achieve what you wanted, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731627/1291157) might answer your question.

Here's a snippet on how the user list and the processes per user can be accessed.

```
import psutil
a = psutil.users()
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    p.cpu_times()
    if p.username() == a[0].name:
        print p.cpu_times().user
        print p.memory_percent()
```